# Android Development: How mirroring applications works?

Tags: android, android-studio, mirror

How screen mirroring application works on Android devices?

A piece of data has to be passed from the phone to whatever device is mirroring the phone.

Is that data an image? If yes does taking 60 screenshots per second and sending that data to the mirroring device possible on the phone level, or It is to performance heavy ?

**Note:** "Mirroring": what appears on the phone screen is appearing on the other device(the mirroring device)

Comment: What do you mean by "screen mirroring"? Where is the "mirroring" occurring?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Sorry, the question has been updated. "Mirroring": what appears on the phone screen is appearing on the other device(the mirroring device)

Comment: When you say other device - where is that other device/what is other device? Over the internet, via USB, local WiFi? Another Android phone or a PC or a smart TV?

Comment: Over local wifi. The original plan was to configure a local server (over local wifi) which establishes a socket connection with the phone, receives the data (images) and display them in a browser forming a video. This part should be feasible, but there may be an issue with the capability of the android phone to take 60 screenshots a second.

Comment: The socket uses UDP protocol

Comment: Okay, then device to PC browser? Note that for development there is [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) which handles mirroring to PC over USB/Wifi. But you haven't described your use case clearly to exclude that solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224499/discussion-between-eeah-and-morrison-chang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the chat:

1. Developer mode on Android device can be enabled
2. PC browser is requirement
3. Interaction with Android device from PC is not a requirement

Most likely you should be able to modify or find a modification to how [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) behaves.

Given how obvious it would be to send the Android display feed to a browser look to [Using a webclient instead sdl app](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/313) github issue thread for possible solutions or avenues for investigation.